# Should I reboot my phone regularly?

Tags: reboot

After noticing that my Galaxy S3 sometimes grew slow after a week or so of not rebooting, I set up a Llama task which reboots my phone automatically every night (under certain conditions).

My question is simply are there any downsides to rebooting a phone daily?

Comment: Why does it slow down? That's the question that should be asked, there's a few of those questions posted here about [1](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/40908/how-can-i-find-which-app-slows-down-my-phone), [2](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19057/how-do-i-know-which-applications-slows-down-the-phone), [3](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/32734/why-is-my-phone-slow) to mention but a few.... *use the search bar with keywords 'slow down' or 'performance issue'*

Comment: I expect any OS to slow down over time to some extent. Certainly I have to reboot my Windows machine every week or so as well. If rebooting is not a problem, then I don't have a problem.

Comment: Android != Windows, thusly **should not** have to be rebooting Android constantly, this is a clear sign there's a problematic app that is causing the handset to run like treacle - I suspect there's a few wakelocks being acquired and not released which has a performance impact. FYI - as an example, as because Android uses Linux kernel, the uptime on my handset is around the 424 hours mark since last reboot and no slow downs. Should diagnose as per the linkys I have mentioned in previous comment.... :)

Answer (score 2):

To answer your question, there is no downside if you reboot your phone on a regular basis.

off topic: Android OS should not require a reboot, or it should not slow down your phone that much that you feel to reboot it. There may be a problem with an app or something, but that is for another topic.

Answer (score 1):

Check Task Manager to see if any unnecessary resource hungry application is running in the background. I use Clean Master to keep the machine out of junk. These make my device somewhat faster.